# Replicate data on one port to other ports

Tags: node.js, windows, networking, udp

UDP (unicast) data is being received on a single port. I have a program (closed source tool, not created by me) that needs to listen to this data. Multiple instances of this tool need to be run, with the same data being fed in to all instances. I can only have one instance of the tool listening to the single port at any one time though.

How would I go about duplicating the data being received on this port to a set of unique ports so I can use multiple instances of the tool?

I haven't found a solution to try and report my problems back. The solution might be a NodeJS one that rebroadcasts data or potentially doable on an OS level. Maybe even router level with portforwarding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by creating a NodeJS server to listen to the UDP port, and resend the data to the ports I wanted.

```
var portMappings = [5000,5001,5002];
server.on('message', function(msg,rinfo){

    for(var i = 0; i < portMappings.length; i++)
    {
        server.send(msg,0,msg.length,portMappings[i],"127.0.0.1");
    }

});
```

Warning: If you use 'localhost' for the IP destination like I initially did, the CPU load gets massive. I didn't have this problem after switching to '127.0.0.1'.